# move view to reset frame and keyboard at the same time

Tags: ios, keyboard-events, objectoutputstream

I have view to type message as shown below.

[image]

Now, when I type message, the keyboard appears and the box should move just above keyboard as shown in figure below.

[image]

**my problem** 
 They keyboard animation and view animation occur at different time. Keyboard appears first and then view appears. Even if i tried to set animation time to any, they occur at different time.

**How should I solve my problem?**

Please, suggest me way to solve it so that keyboard and view animates to show as if they are of same view. Both animation should occur at exact time so that they look like same view appeared at a time.

**what i tried**

my view did load has following code

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

now keyboard show function look like

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
  NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [note userInfo];
  CGFloat duration = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:
 ^{
   //chat_typingView is name for typing view
   chat_typingView.frame = CGRectMake(chat_typingView.frame.origin.x,
                                                238,
                                                chat_typingView.frame.size.width,
                                                chat_typingView.frame.size.height);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check if your chat_typinfView is First responder before do the animation and disable Autolayout (very important).

```
if ([chat_typingView isFirstResponder]) {
  // Do the animation 
}
```

PS is recommendable to subscribe to the notification on viewWillApper instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup in one of my apps and I do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardShowed:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    /*** FOR AUTOLAYOUT MODIFICATIONS & ADDITIONS @ RUNTIME ***/

    self.defaultViewFrame = self.myView.frame
}


- (void) keyboardShowed:(NSNotification*)notification {

    //GET KEYBOARD FRAME
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    //CONVERT KEYBOARD FRAME TO MATCH THE OUR COORDINATE SYSTEM (FOR UPSIDEDOWN ROTATION)
    CGRect convertedFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:self.view.window];

    //..... do something with the convertedFrame (in your case convertedFrame.origin.y)
}

- (void) keyboardHidden:(NSNotification*)notification {

    //RESTORE ORIGINAL STATE 

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:.3f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                        self.myView.frame = self.defaultViewFrame;
                    }
                        completion:nil];
}
```